# Comparing two arrays of objects and return one array with common values using loadash

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to array of objects which lets say look like this :

```
var result1 = [
{id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
{id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
{id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
{id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
]; 

var result2 = [
{id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
{id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];
```

how to get objects which are present in both the arrays using loadash?
and also what if we have N number of arrays of object and we want to compare them all and get common values in an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var result1 = [
  {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
  {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
  {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
]; 

var result2 = [
  {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
  {id:15, name:'Pe', type:'usefghjr', username:'pete'},
];

let op = result2.filter(e => result1.some(el => el.id === e.id))

console.log(op);
```

**What if i have more arrays**

```js
var result1 = [
  {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
  {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
  {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
]; 

var result2 = [
  {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
  {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
  {id:15, name:'Pe', type:'usefghjr', username:'pete'},
];

var result3 = [{id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'}];

let array = [result1,result2,result3]

let op = result2.filter(ele => array.every(el => el.some(val => val.id === ele.id)))

console.log(op);
```

Comment: What if we have 4 or more arrays?

Comment: I have found a way of doing this using loadash 

    let finalArray = _.intersectionBy(result1,result2,result3, 'id');

Answer (score 0):

You could build a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with all `id` and filter the arrays by checking common objects with same `id`.

```js
var result1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'Sandra', type: 'user', username: 'sandra' }, { id: 2, name: 'John', type: 'admin', username: 'johnny2' }, { id: 3, name: 'Peter', type: 'user', username: 'pete' }, { id: 4, name: 'Bobby', type: 'user', username: 'be_bob' }],
    result2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'John', type: 'admin', username: 'johnny2' }, { id: 3, name: 'Peter', type: 'user', username: 'pete' }],
    common = [result1, result2].reduce((a, b) => {
        var s = new Set(a.map(({ id }) => id));
        return b.filter(({ id }) => s.has(id));            
    });

console.log(common);
```